# Analytics broken on Marshmallow?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm using analytics and while compiling I get this proguard warnings:

```
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning: com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzam: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
Warning: com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzam: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils
```

<sup>and much more.</sup>

I'm using these dependencies:

```gradle
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
```

Is this a bug? Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Related: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183116

Comment: I'm playing with the proguard rule `-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**` but I cannot create release builds.

Comment: You should mark [Barry Irvine's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32115639/1747491) as correct.  The problem lies in the removal of `org.apache.http` from Android, which was addressed by Google.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adding to proguard

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

seems to fix

Comment: fix the build but the Google Play Services 7.8.0 will not be able to communicate with the Internet without Apache HTTP so no Ads, no Analytics, no Maps...

Answer (score 7):

I think if you add the legacy Http support to the build.gradle of your app (just inside the android section) then it should resolve the issue until GMS and other libraries move to the non-removed classes

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' // Need until GMS upgraded
}
```

See [this page](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client) for official documentation.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bug, we need to include all optional dependencies (http is now optional in API 23) when running Proguard, as Proguard is very strict about seeing all the needed classes.

The problem is that if your app project doesn't declare that it needs http, then Progard won't be configured to receive it as a library jar.

A temporary fix would be to make your app declare that it needs it, but that's not really what you want either. (see the other answers)

Making Proguard not warn about missing classes is probably not a good idea, but it's possible too (see the other answers)

Anyway, we'll fix this in the final 1.4. It should show up in the next beta (beta2), next week probably (week of 2015/09/07)

Comment: Great news. So does that mean that we will be able to tell proguard that we have an optional dependency?

Comment: No, we'll just configure proguard with the optional libraries too (right now it's only the http legacy one), in case a dependency use it. If we get to a point where there is a huge number of optional library and it's making proguard slower, then we'll let you configure this manually, but for now there's no need.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a bug, note that Android Marshmallow is not released yet, and according to comments on Google+ when "Android Developers" made a post about the SDK, there are many bugs with proguard and other stuff. Wait until a newer version of the SDK comes out.

Answer (score 0):

According to the API 22-23 diff changes, the org.apache.http.* packages have been removed as of Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) API Level 23.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes.html

via : http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/m-developer-preview-3-final-sdk.html

Comment: Sorry. Not enough rep to make a comment. But I just came across this. Hope it helps those who missed the diff removal.

Comment: @Kosso Well, then answer many new questions, if you are the first one to answer and get an approved answer, you get +15 reputation ^^